# Informatica Audit framework

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using the auditing framework like-
Main mapping-> assignment task -> audit task

Even if I am having multiple pipelines in the mapping, I am getting the TOTAL successful records inserted using the $targetsuccessrows variable.

For example- for 4 records each in the pipeline within mapping, $targetsuccessrows is giving me value =8

Is there any way I can get values as 4 and 4 for each pipeline within mapping?

Comment: Anything is possible! :) Some details would help answering your question though. Please share the implementation details so it will be possible to review and advise. Look at http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html for some examples, if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.
What you can do (but that requires manual setup) is to create a command task running after the session; in this command task you can use the predefined variables for individual target row counts ($PMTargetName@TableName, you can find details and examples in the Advanced Workflow guide for PowerCenter, chapter Working With Session Parameters). This way you can e.g. save the exact numbers per target instance to a flat file.
In a following session you can then source this file and save the numbers to your auditing framework.

To be honest I have refrained from doing so in my own framework, so please don't ask me for an example, I don't have one.